# How to create a QMainWindow using Qt-Designer and pyside6?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside6

Using `PyQt6` I can instantiate a `QMainWindow` using something like:

```
import sys

from PyQt6.uic import loadUi
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    exit(app.exec())
```

The equivalent `pyside6` code:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        QUiLoader().load("mainwindow.ui", self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    exit(app.exec())
```

This does **not** work because second parameter of `QUiLoader().load()` is the `parent` and thus I should add the resulting widget to my `MainWindow` thus preventing me to design the whole Main Window in Qt-Designer.

I know I could instantiate the whole `MainWindow` from `main`, such as:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QUiLoader().load("mainwindow.ui", None)
window.show()
exit(app.exec())
```

... but that would prevent me to subclass `QMainWindow` to add my own code.

What is the right way to port `PyQt6` code to `pyside6`?

Comment: AFAIK PySide6 still does not support doing the same thing loadUi does (and I often ask myself why they don't). You can only use pyside-uic classes. The only viable alternative is to just create the central widgets of those main windows as a basic form (QWidget) and then use `setCentralWidget()`. This obviously means that you won't be able to embed menus, dock bars and tool bars from Designer.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been marked as a duplicate, it really isn't. The other question doesn't generate menu bars and other features of a `QMainWindow`, and its answers do not do this either. @ZioByte, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @MikkelRoald-Arbøl No, in the end I ditched PySide6 and kept using PyQt6. IMHO this is a major flaw in PySide*.